# there's any way to use foreach with AND?

Tags: php, foreach, http-post

```
foreach(($_POST["msg"] as $mg) AND ($_POST["control"] as $id))
   {
    echo $mg;
    echo $id;
   }
```

i need make something like that, any way to do? i'm trying to get 10 mysql records and edit all of them

Comment: How can a POST contain an array?

Comment: @jef - this **is** possible. You can give name attributes like `name=data[]` and that is converted into an array in `$_POST['data']`.

Comment: @Lix, yeah you are right, I've forgot that. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that won't work. The closest thing I can see to what you're trying to do is:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST["msg"]); $i++) {
    echo $_POST["msg"][$i];
    echo $_POST["control"][$i];
}
```

Assuming that "msg" and "control" will always contain the same amount of items.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both `$_POST['msg']` and `$_POST['control']` are actually arrays, have numeric keys (thanks [@iMoses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318508/theres-any-way-to-use-foreach-with-and#comment18167751_13318532)), and have the same length, you could use a for loop -

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST["msg"]); $i++){
  $mg = $_POST['msg'][$i];
  $id = $_POST['control'][$i];
}
```

Comment: Assuming the keys are numeric, otherwise you'll need `next` `current` and `end`